# Delay between creating AD account and seeing it in Exchange

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2007, user-accounts

Wondering if there is a delay between the Creating a new user account in the AD management console and the user appearing in the Exchange Management Console.

Using Exchange Server 2007, created the account about 30 mins ago in AD console, still hasn't shown up in Exchange Console or Dynamic Distribution List.

Comment: Are the domain controller and Exchange server in question at the same Active Directory site?

Comment: For new users, this is not important; user account actions are pushed through replication instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably doing it thru Active Directory Users and Computers.  Create new users via the exchange management console, choose new mailbox, choose new user instead of existing user.After providing the AD information configure the mailbox as normal. The reason for your current delay is most likley replication between DCs

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I just added him manually by choosing Existing User.  You're correct that I did it first through AD, was just wondering how long the delay is.  Is there a way to check it?

Answer (score 0):

We have to create the mailbox using the Exchange Management Console, separate from AD management tools. I.e., create the user in AD, then open the Exchange Management Console and create a mailbox for an existing user, then they can use email.